Database client not connecting to PostgreSQL
So, I made a docker-compose file where I run a PostgreSQL databse, and everything is fine, the container shows up in the docker desktop, but when I try to connect to it through "Database Client" in VS code it shows a bunch of unknown symbols and the username. Any suggestions?
Connection parameters
Docker-compose file
Connection error
I tried to connect to my local psql databse that is supposedly in a container (I'm new to docker)

I was never happy with database features/extension in VSCode. Just spawn a pgAdmin container. Refer to this answer to know how.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to include the relevant source code, Compose file (at least a useful extract), and error message in plain text?

How can I add an error text if it's just unknown symbols? And whats wrong with images? Im not showing any personal info, and clicking on a link doesn't seem hard to me. is there a problem with links?
